# Iterating through two elements simultaneously

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div with input fields and corresponding select option tags. I want to be able to iterate through the first input and then the first select option then the second input and second select option etc., I am currently iterating through them both but I am getting the 3 text input's first then the select options. Is there a way to iterate one element at a time for each?

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="inputDiv">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="keys"></input>
        <select name = "choices">
            <option value="null"></option>
            <option value="text">Text</option>
            <option value="note">Note</option>
            <option value="dd">Drop Down</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>
```

and my Jquery

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    $("input").each(function() {
        $("#form").append('<p>'+$(this).val()+'</p>');
    });
    $("select").each(function() {
        switch($(this).val()) { 
            case "text":
                $("#form").append('<p> <input type="text"/> <button class="remInput">Remove</button> </p>'); 
                break;
            case "note":
                $("#form").append('<p> <textarea></textarea> <button class="remInput">Remove</button> </p> '); 
                break;
            case "dd":
                $("#form").append('<div class="ddCreator"> <button class="ddAddInput">Add Another Field</button> <p class="ddP"> <input type="text" name="ddText"/> </p> <button class="ddSubmit">Submit</button> </div>');
                break;
        }
    });

    $('#inputDiv').empty();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the children of each p

```
$('p').children().each(function(i, elem) {
   if (elem.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
       // found input
   } else if (elem.nodeName === 'SELECT') {
       // found select
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems kind of obvious now.